Issue with FlutterBluePlus: Handling Device Scanning and Selecting Devices in Flutter App
I am working on a Flutter app that uses the flutter_blue_plus package to scan and connect to BLE devices. I am facing an issue where I'm trying to handle the device scanning process and allow the user to select a device. However, I’m getting an error with how I'm using FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning and handling device selection.
Below is the relevant code for the Bluetooth device scanning and selection process:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/blocs/add_device_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/blocs/ble/device_discovery_bloc.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/utils/values.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/widgets/bottom_sheet_background.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/widgets/one_line_text.dart';
import 'package:whizpad_lan_flutter/models/device_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'button_add_device.dart';

class InputDeviceMacBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputDeviceMacBottomSheet({
    Key? key,
    required this.screenSize,
    required this.parentContext,
    required this.deviceType,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size screenSize;
  final BuildContext parentContext;
  final DeviceType? deviceType;

  @override
  _InputDeviceMacBottomSheetState createState() =>
      _InputDeviceMacBottomSheetState();
}

class _InputDeviceMacBottomSheetState extends State<InputDeviceMacBottomSheet> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  late AddDeviceBloc addDeviceBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    addDeviceBloc = Provider.of<AddDeviceBloc>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<Device?>(
        stream: addDeviceBloc.selectedDevice,
        builder: (context, selectedDevice) {
          return StreamBuilder<String>(
              stream: addDeviceBloc.selectedDeviceId,
              builder: (context, selectedDeviceMac) {
                if (selectedDeviceMac.hasData == false) {
                  return SizedBox();
                }

                textEditingController.text = selectedDeviceMac.data!;
                textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(
                    offset: textEditingController.text.length);

                return MyBottomSheetBackground(
                  screenSize: widget.screenSize,
                  title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterDeviceMacPage,
                  subtitle: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterDeviceMac,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.deviceMac,
                                  style: textStyle45pt),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: TextFieldContainer(
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: textEditingController,
                                    onEditingComplete: () {
                                      addDeviceBloc.updateSelectedMac(
                                          textEditingController.text);
                                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                    },
                                    cursorColor: primaryBlackColor,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterMac,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: textStyle30ptGrey,
                                    ),
                                    textCapitalization:
                                        TextCapitalization.characters,
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(inputMacRegExp),
                                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      StreamBuilder<bool>(
                          stream: FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning,
                          builder: (context, isScanning) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.anyDeviceMac,
                                        style: textStyleBold),
                                    if (isScanning.hasData && isScanning.data != null)
                                      Container(
                                        width: 16.0,
                                        height: 16.0,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                            Colors.grey,
                                          ),
                                          strokeWidth: 2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                      Expanded(
                        child: StreamBuilder<List<Device?>>(
                          stream: Provider.of<DeviceDiscoveryBloc>(
                                  widget.parentContext)
                              .targetDevices(widget.deviceType),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                              return Container();
                            }
                            return ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Divider(
                                  height: 2.0,
                                );
                              },
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length + 1,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                if (index == snapshot.data!.length) {
                                  return StreamBuilder<bool>(
                                      stream:
                                          FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning,
                                      builder: (context, isScanning) {
                                        if (isScanning.data == null ||
                                            isScanning.data == true) {
                                          return SizedBox();
                                        }
                                        return Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                                  .bottonDeviceNotFound),
                                              GestureDetector(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                                      .refresh,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                                      decoration:
                                                          TextDecoration.underline),
                                                ),
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  FlutterBluePlus.instance
                                                      .startScan(
                                                          timeout: Duration(
                                                              seconds: 10));
                                                },
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      });
                                }
                                String macStr = '';
                                final Device? device = snapshot.data![index];
                                macStr = device?.getDecodedAdvServiceData();
                                return ListTile(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Provider.of<AddDeviceBloc>(context, listen: false)
                                        .selectDevice(snapshot.data![index]!);
                                  },
                                  tileColor: Colors.white,
                                  title: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
                                      child: OneLineText("$macStr")),
                                  trailing: selectedDevice.data?.deviceId ==
                                          snapshot.data![index]?.deviceId
                                      ? Icon(Icons.check_circle_sharp, color: Colors.green)
                                      : SizedBox(),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  bottomButton: MyButton(
                    title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.add,
                    onPress: (textEditingController.text == "" ||
                            textEditingController.text.length < 12)
                        ? null
                        : () {
                            Navigator.pop(context, textEditingController.text);
                          },
                  ),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}

Issue:
I am using flutter_blue_plus to scan BLE devices and allow users to select them. I'm getting issues in handling the scanning stream with FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning, and also I am not sure if I'm handling the device selection correctly.
I have a StreamBuilder for isScanning, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct API for handling the scanning status or if I should use isScanningStream. Additionally, I need help confirming that I am handling the device selection process correctly by extracting the necessary details from the scan result.
Questions:
Is FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning the right API to check for ongoing scanning, or should I be using isScanningStream?
How should I handle the device selection process properly using flutter_blue_plus, especially for obtaining the device's MAC address and passing it to my AddDeviceBloc?
